# Using haxe.macro.TypeTools fails

Tags: macros, haxe

I'm trying to debug a library which uses `haxe.macro.TypeTools::findField`. I've created a simple code for that:

```
package;

using haxe.macro.TypeTools;

class Main
{   
    public function new()
    {   
        var test = findField(Child, "hello");
        trace(test);
    }
}

class Base
{
    private function hello()
    {
    }
}

class Child extends Base
{
    public function new() {}
}
```

However I'm getting error `Unknown identifier : findField`. Is this because it can only be used in build macro context?

[This](https://github.com/fponticelli/edge/blob/3b4623172c0ecc426a940cc0c9d34c7e660ce8a2/src/edge/core/macro/BuildSystem.hx#L57) is what I'm trying to emulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, function `findField()` is not from the `haxe.macro.TypeTools`.
It is [a helper function from `edge.core.macro.Macros`](https://github.com/fponticelli/edge/blob/3b4623172c0ecc426a940cc0c9d34c7e660ce8a2/src/edge/core/macro/Macros.hx#L71).

To use it without a class path, import it's class with a wildcard `import edge.core.macro.Macros.*`

Secondly, `findField()` should be used in a build macro context only, since it expects `Array<Field>`, which is obtained by `haxe.macro.Context.getBuildFields()`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: how is https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/2931fb9d15d5df4cb8b59c94cee47c7a993b6d1b/std/haxe/macro/TypeTools.hx#L346 used then?

Comment: Ok, I read through static extensions doc page, so it would be called like: `SomeClassType.findField("field", true);`

Comment: Yes, but only in a macro context